# Power Dissipation in Subtractor Op-amp Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, voltage-measurement, single-supply-op-amp

How much power can be assumed to be dissipated through the resistors of an op-amp configured as a subtractor like the one below?

[image]

Theoretically, a very very small current should pass, but I don't know what the minimum power dissipation I should choose for a real circuit for, say, R3 and R4 being 22 kΩ and R1 and R2 being 20 kΩ.

Comment: It depends on what V1 and V2 are, but unless you're doing something weird, "not much" is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Hi Samwel, you know the general rule of opamps that no current flows into the inputs, right? Knowing this, the answer becomes really easy to calculate once you know V1 and V2, since that sets Vout, too.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Thanks a lot